# How to know where a static method is called in a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a very large project and I would like to know where a public static method is called by other methods in the whole project. I usually do that with other methods by right clicking on the method and then select References -> Workspace (shift+ctrl+G) but this doesn't work with static methods.

Can someone suggest me a way to figure that out?

Comment: Hm, rather sounds like a bug or a user error. I do think that any decent IDE that can lookup "usages", can do that for static and non-static methods.

Comment: Search techniques depends on IDE to IDE. Which IDE you are using??

Comment: @VishwaRatna Eclipse

Comment: @AdamAmin, select the method and press `ctrl + alt + h` , you will get all the callers.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a string search for the name of the method. Click _Search_ menu and choose _File..._ menu item.

Comment: If all else fails... make the method private,check for compile errors and pray no one used reflection to call the method..